# computer science corpus for language model training

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp, text, ai

I am looking for a domain-specific computer science corpus of at least 20M words (preferable >50M words), for the purpose of training a language model in it.

Is there anything out-of-the-box that I could use? *I tried to look for the sciBERT corpus, but can not find how to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Could the [Semantic Scholar Open Research Corpus (S2ORC)](https://github.com/allenai/s2orc) be of help?

S2ORC contains 12.7M+ full text papers, of which 7.2% pertain to computer science (according to [their paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.18653/v1/2020.acl-main.447), at p. 4974).